# Issue using couchbase lite java on Windows XP

Tags: java, javafx, windows-xp, couchbase-lite

I am using couchbase lite for java (couchbase-lite-java-1.3.1) for my JavaFX application.
My code is working well on Mac OS X, Windows 7/10.
Now I am trying to make it work on Windows XP but I am getting the following error:

> Executing C:\Documents and
>   Settings\Administrator\Desktop\Testy\Testy\dist\run618830020\Testy.jar
>   using platform C:\Documents and
>   Settings\Administrator\Desktop\NetBeans_JavaSE_7.4_Portable\App\jdk\jre/bin/java
>   Exception in Application constructor
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
>   at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) at
>   sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
>   Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to construct Application
>   instance: class org.company.business.testy.Main at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:907)
>   at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(LauncherImpl.java:182)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$161(LauncherImpl.java:819)
>   at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
>   at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
>   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
>   at
>   com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
>   at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method) at
>   com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
>   ... 1 more Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Documents and
>   Settings\Administrator\Local
>   Settings\Temp\NetBeans_JavaSE_7.4_PortableTemp\CouchbaseLiteJavaForestDB.dll:
>   The specified procedure could not be found at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method) at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1941) at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1824) at
>   java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:809) at
>   java.lang.System.load(System.java:1086) at
>   com.couchbase.lite.util.NativeLibUtils.loadLibrary(NativeLibUtils.java:45)
>   at com.couchbase.lite.store.ForestDBStore.(ForestDBStore.java:75) at
>   java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) at
>   java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264) at
>   com.couchbase.lite.Database.createStoreInstance(Database.java:1156) at
>   com.couchbase.lite.Database.open(Database.java:1221) at
>   com.couchbase.lite.Manager.openDatabase(Manager.java:335) at
>   com.couchbase.lite.Manager.getDatabase(Manager.java:299) at
>   org.company.business.testy.dbms.DBMS.initDatabase(DBMS.java:38) at
>   org.company.business.testy.dbms.DBMS.(DBMS.java:23) at
>   org.company.business.testy.dbms.DAO.(DAO.java:28) at
>   org.company.business.testy.Main.(Main.java:91) ... 13 more Exception
>   running application org.company.business.testy.Main

I use the same Netbeans project for Mac OS X, Windows 7 and for Windows XP. 
Do you have some info about this problem? It is trying to use a procedure in CouchbaseLiteJavaForestDB.dll...

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reached out Couchbase Lite dev team and they advised me to remove ForestDB jar lib and to use SQLite as storage engine. Now it's working well on Windows XP.

https://forums.couchbase.com/t/issue-using-couchbase-lite-java-on-windows-xp/11405/17